# GR vs QM: if gravity is a force then what is space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, quantum-gravity

As described by the GR theory, gravity is the curvature of space-time.
On the other hand in quantum mechanics gravity tends to be described as a force, related to it's hypothetical particle called graviton...if that's the case i.e if gravity is a force then what is space-time according to QM?

Comment: I don't recall seeing gravity in QM

Comment: Jim do you recall seeing space-time in QM?

Comment: I think so, when you use tensor formalization. I might be thinking of QFT though. But it was Minkowski spacetime, which is basically spacetime without gravity. I'm pretty sure that using a metric with gravity doesn't jive with QM or QFT. If it did, there'd be no issue combining quantum and GR

Answer (score 1):

This won’t be the best answer but it’s AN answer.

In QM spacetime is the framework that the forces act in. It is a rigid, unchanging framework that allows precise calculations to be made. QMechanics use Newtonian principles. That’s why the term force is used in describing gravity’s effects.

Einstein pushed the boundaries of Newton’s principles and proved the framework is different at every point in the universe and is subject to change through causality.

In GR spacetime is part of the dynamic, changing whole. Therefore in GR spacetime is not suitable for use as a framework because no two observers can agree on simultaneous events. Their perspectives are different.

QM cannot regard spacetime as dynamic because calculations would be impossible. This is the reason why GR and QM are irreconcilable and they don’t need to be any other way.

QM is useful for the microscopic world.

GR works best with large phenomena.